Copy part of the directory alongside files to target directory and files
I made a backup of a directory in case of a configuration failure. I'm not really sure how to copy - overwrite this back to the target directory (alongside its entire content).
Source: /var/vault/0_make_backup/_etc_sudoers.d_/**etc/sudoers.d/files**
Target: /etc/sudoers.d/files
I tried using cp -rf /var/vault/0_make_backup/_etc_sudoers.d_/etc /etc, but files in the target /etc/sudoers.d/ were not overwritten.
Do you have any idea hows to accomplish this?

Please use code formatting \something`to show the actual paths. You have paths with some mix of_and*and because those have effect on formatting, it's not clear what the actual paths are. Do you mean/var/vault/0_make_backup/etc_sudoers.d/etc/sudoers.d/files, or literally /var/vault/0_make_backup/etc_sudoers.d/etc/sudoers.d/files`?

Sorry, the ** was from formatting i guess. As for the _ its in place of / as replacement for the "name" of complete actual path.
Anyway i found that it was just  adding * like using grep.
cp -rf /var/vault/0_make_backup/etc_sudoers.d/* /etc/

This overwrite existing file/folder and add new file/folder recursively to target directory
cp -rf /var/vault/0_make_backup/etc_sudoers.d/* /etc/

Pop up said : You can accept your own answer in 2 days
